# tkinter .get() returns nothing when starting the class outside the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter`s .get() method. I use a simple tkinter menu to add the 9'th value to a csv while recording. While running a class for this menu from a script where the class was written, it works just fine. However, when trying to call this app from other script, I get no data appended. So, how to receive the data from .get() method while working with this menu in the other script? Here is a sample of my code (this is a part of an app and a way I start it from a script where it is located):

```
from myo_interface import MyoRaw
import csv
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys
import pandas as pd

class recorderForData(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.doTick = True

        self.title("Data recording")
        self.m = MyoRaw(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else None)

        self.v = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.v.set("")
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.v)

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.B1 = tkinter.Button(self, text="Start recording", command=self.process_emg)
        self.B2 = tkinter.Button(self, text="Stop recording", command=self.stop_recording)
        self.B3 = tkinter.Button(self, text="Clean csv", command=self.clear_csv)
        self.rows_number = tkinter.Label(self, text=self.counter)

    def process_emg(self, emg, times):
        name = self.v.get()
        with open('own_test.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
            writing = csv.writer(file)
            writing.writerow(emg+(name,))

    def start_app(self):
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.B1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.B2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.B3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        self.rows_number.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.mainloop()


def main():
    rd = recorderForData()
    rd.start_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is how I call it from the outside:

```
import test_record


def recordData():
    rd = test_record.recorderForData()
    rd.start_app()
```

Comment: what have you done to debug this? what is `self.v.get()` returning? Is it being called when you think it's being called? Is `self.v` what you think it is? The call to `get` is inside the function `process_emg` which is never called by any of the code you posted.

Comment: Fixed it using your comment, Bryan. Thanks!

Comment: Accept your own answer, please

Comment: I will be able to do it in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in `v.get()`. Changing it to `entry.get()` solves it.